# Python CSV writer: How to write upc code with leading zero as string?

Tags: python, string, csv

I am using Python with `csv` writer to export a csv containing UPC codes (which occasionally contain leading zeros) in several columns.

The exported sheet should look something like this:

```
name, upc    
Blue Perfume, "0853520006427"   
Red Cologne, "0223520006427"   
Beige Tanner, "8292930112345"  
...
```

In my attempt to achieve this I have tried to add double quotes like so:

```
productSKU = '\"' + productSKU + '\"'
```

but this ends up outputing double double-quotes to the csv file like so:

```
""0853520006427""
```

I've read online suggestions to try adding an = to the beginning of the sheet so that Excel parses the cell as a string but this is unwanted behavior as it leaves the entry in the resulting csv file like this:

```
="0853520006427"
```

as opposed to this:

```
"0853520006427"
```

What is the proper way of achieving this end result with `csv` writer?

**EDIT**

Here is a quick python script I wrote to test with:

```
import csv

filename = 'output.csv'

with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    rowData = ['Blue Shampoo', '0853520006427']
    writer.writerow(rowData)

    rowData = ['Blue Shampoo', '\"0853520006427\"']
    writer.writerow(rowData)

    rowData = ['Blue Shampoo', '=\"0853520006427\"']
    writer.writerow(rowData)

    rowData = ['Blue Shampoo', '\'0853520006427']
    writer.writerow(rowData)
```

Notice the resulting data:

```
Blue Shampoo,0853520006427
Blue Shampoo,"""0853520006427"""
Blue Shampoo,"=""0853520006427"""
Blue Shampoo,'0853520006427
```

Comment: Why do you care what the csv data looks like? Whether or not there are quotes around those numbers makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  People will be quicker to help if you provide a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) they can copy-paste into their own development tools.

Comment: I suspect the question has something to do with what happens when you open the CSV in an editor like Excel. If it's not explicitly marked as a string then the leading zero gets dropped. If this is the case then the issue is with opening the file, not saving it.

Comment: a leading single quote should preserve leading zeros

Comment: Is this just being opened in a spreadsheet application? Or are you reading it with something (programmatically) else later on ?

Comment: Tell Excel to treat that SKU column as text

Comment: @Aran-Fey : The csv data must contain the UPC code around single double-quotes as the resulting csv file will be parsed by various other utilities programmatically as JacobIRR mentioned. Using anything but single double-quotes around the UPC code leads to inconsistent parsing across the other utilities

Comment: @JacobIRR The file will be read by other utilities that interpret the data literally. Using single double quotes around the UPC code maintains the data consistent through to the end of operations performed on the sheet. Else, I end up with a sheet that includes useless symbols scattered throughout

Comment: If the quotes really make a difference, then this data isn't csv data, it's something else. You won't be able to use the `csv` for this; you'll have to write the file manually.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't understand.  The data is perfectly inline with the RFC 4180 csv standard https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2

Comment: Yes, it's valid csv. But in csv, `foo` is exactly equivalent to `"foo"`. If they're not equivalent, then it's not csv.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I agree, however certain applications parse `01` as `1` since it appears to be a number. However, `01` the string, is not infact equivalent to `1` the integer.

Comment: @CAB thank you, I've updated the post to include an example to test with

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to explicitly provide a quote on all your data while writing to csv, and select `QUOTE_ALL` as the quoting strategy:

```
In [23]: import csv
    ...: 
    ...: filename = 'output.csv'
    ...: 
    ...: with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    ...:     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    ...:     rowData = ['Blue Shampoo', '0853520006427']
    ...:     writer.writerow(rowData)
    ...:
```

Gives output:

> "Blue Shampoo","0853520006427"

However, this will also put your first field within quotes (which will be consistent across all fields, so should be ok I guess).

Since the csv module [only supports 4 types of quotes](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL) (`QUOTE_ALL, QUOTE_MINIMAL, QUOTE_NONE, QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`), this is the only option you have if you use the csv module. You could of course write to the file without the csv module in a csv compliant fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing on my end, and it seems that enclosing the UPC code in double quotes doesn't help prevent EXCEL from reading the field as numbers. Same thing would happen in pandas. You can certainly do something like this:
`rowData = ['Blue Shampoo', "'0853520006427'"]`, which would output `"Blue Shampoo,'0853520006427'`. Excel would read the UPC code in as a string, but it'll have single quotes around it.